# partial declarations of must not specify

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am getting an error for "partial declarations of ... must not specify different base classes"

```
namespace CameraControl.windows
{
    public partial class GantryXYZW_TEST : Window
    {
        public GantryXYZW_TEST()
        {
```

The error comes from the line of

```
public partial class GantryXYZW_TEST : Window
```

The XAML is:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="CameraControl.windows.GantryXYZW_TEST"
```

Comment: Try being explicit with "Window".  Search your entire project for the other declaration,and use the same base class(es)

Comment: `MetroWindow` is not `Window`.

Answer (score 1):

As commenter SLaks alludes to…

You either need to edit the XAML so that your window class is `Window` and not `controls:MetroWindow`, or you need to edit your C# so that your window class is `GantryXYZW_TEST : MetroWindow` and not `GantryXYZW_TEST : Window`.